# JS - getElementsByClassName array, then get elements inside the array

Tags: javascript

I have a svg script with a few rects:

```
<g class="1">
    <rect x="80.181" y="156.8" width="64.394" height="54.973"/>
</g>
<g class="2">
    <rect x="147.067" y="156.8" width="23.89" height="54.973"/>
</g>
<g class="1">
    <rect x="173.45" y="156.8" width="22.433" height="54.973"/>
</g>
<g class="3">
    <rect x="198.375" y="156.8" width="39.668" height="54.973"/>
</g>

(...)
```

And I want to create a function that defines the fill of all rects inside class, for example, 1. Something like:

```
function FillRect() {
    var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('1');

    for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        document.rect[i].querySelector('rect').style.fill="blue";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do the last `document.rect[i].querySelector` part.

Comment: After you created the `rect` variable, why would you try to access it as a property on `document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
var rect = document.querySelectorAll(".1 rect");
for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
    rect[i].style.fill="blue";
}
```

Comment: Yes, much better to just put the additional query into the original selector and let the query engine do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need refer to the document object.

```
function FillRect() {
    var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('1');

    for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
        rect[i].querySelector('rect').style.fill="blue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function FillRect() {
    var rect = document.getElementsByClassName('1');

```
for (var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++) {
    rect[i].getElementsByTagName('rect').style.fill="blue";
}}
```

This should do what you want. You may consider jQuery if you want.